# How to get ClientContext in Sharepoint Online with JSOM

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, development, jsom

```
var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
```

throws this error,

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: SP is not defined
```

the snippet works fine in SharePoint 2013, Are there .js that I need to load? if yes, how can I make this to work!

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to load the `sp.js` as the following

```
var clientContext;

$(document).ready(function () {
        SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', Getdata);
    });

function Getdata() {
        try {
            clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();                   
        }
        catch (err) {
            alert(err);
        }
    }
```

---

If the above code do not working try to load `init.js`, `SP.Runtime.js` and `SP.js` as the following

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/4.0/1/MicrosoftAjax.js"></script>
<script>


   $(document).ready(function(){
        var scriptbase = "http://SiteURL" + "/_layouts/15/";
       //Do not change the order, scripts should load by order.  
     $.getScript(scriptbase + "init.js",
            function () {
                $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.Runtime.js",
                   function () {
                $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.js", Getdata);
              });
          });
           });


function Getdata()
{
   var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    // your code

context.executeQueryAsync(
      function(){ 

      //On success function

     },
     function(){ 
      //On fail function

     }
  );
}
</script>
```